# Want to keep 1st and last row as static in a table in Jasper subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I am creating PDF report using Jasper. I have main jrxml file and subreport jrxml file. In sub-report, I am passing Data Source object which contains list of XYZ Object. In sub-report I am using jrtable to iterate datasource list. In jrtable, I want 1st row as Label (like Start of data) and last row as Label (like End of data). I want Data Source object start iterating from second row. Is this possible in jrxml?

Comment: apply different style on field if record count = 1 ? if record count 1 --> Style header, otherwise style row, search for conditional style